# Integrating Core Data with a custom class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I've got a Core Data Managed Object Model called **Car** that looks like this:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```

.m

```
@dynamic name;
```

And I have a custom class, called **CarCache**, used to cache downloaded Car details, that looks like this:

.h

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
```

which is persisted using this implementation:

.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init]){
        _name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
```

I'd like to integrate these two models but would like to check I'm not going to run into problems.

Should I make CarCache a subclass of Car? If so, do I need to rewrite the current persistence mechanism (i.e. using NSCoder to use Core Data)? Or should I just initialise/persist the instance variables as normal? E.g.

```
self.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
```

This doesn't feel right 'cos it's an `@property` method in an `init` method.

Or perhaps:

```
super.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
```

==== UPDATE

To clarify what I'm wanting to achieve with my `Car` and `CarCache` classes.

`Car` is used to store details of Car objects locally in Core Data.

`CarCache` is used to store details of Car objects from a web service that regularly change (e.g. location).

At the moment, they each use a separate model which I'd like to avoid if possible. So, I'd like to integrate these two models.

E.g. I could make CarCache a subclass of Car. I haven't had any experience subclassing Core Data models so I'm looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
_name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
```

is correct.

Comment: The question is about integrating Core Data and a custom class. My existing code (i.e. without any integration) looks like your answer. The problem with that is that you end up with 2 instance variables. E.g. _name in CarCache and _name in Car. Hence the question.

Comment: Well, they are two different entities, so they can both have the same attribute name. Of course, this attribute will not be shared. Maybe you should describe what you want to accomplish with your CarCache entity.